# Pulling record from mySQL database only working for userid and not email

Tags: c#, mysql, database

This function works because I search by userid:

```
private void showList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int id = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i <= sqlClient.Count("UserList"); i++)
   {
      Dictionary<string, string> dik = sqlClient.Select("UserList", "userid = " + id);

      var lines = dik.Select(kv => kv.Key + ": " + kv.Value.ToString());
      userList.AppendText(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
      userList.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
      userList.AppendText("--------------------------------------");
      id++;
   }
}
```

This function does not work because I search by email:

```
private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string email = lemail.Text;
   Dictionary<string, string> dik = sqlClient.Select("UserList", "firstname = " + email);
   var lines = dik.Select(kv => kv.Key + ": " + kv.Value.ToString());
   logged.AppendText(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
}
```

This is the error message I receive when I click on the login button:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@aol.com' at line 1

The email I searched for in the database was "aces@aol.com" without quotes.
I'm lead to believe by the error message the @ sign is causing conflict as I know it is a special character but I am having a hard time figuring out what phrase to search for to help me.

Also, here is the function that is being called:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Select(string table, string WHERE)
{
   //This methods selects from the database, it retrieves data from it.
   //You must make a dictionary to use this since it both saves the column
   //and the value. i.e. "age" and "33" so you can easily search for values.

   //Example: SELECT * FROM names WHERE name='John Smith'
   // This example would retrieve all data about the entry with the name "John Smith"

   //Code = Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = Select("names", "name='John Smith'");
   //This code creates a dictionary and fills it with info from the database.

   string query = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + WHERE + "";

   Dictionary<string, string> selectResult = new Dictionary<string, string>();

   if (this.Open())
   {
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
      MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

      try
      {
         while (dataReader.Read())
         {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
               selectResult.Add(dataReader.GetName(i).ToString(), dataReader.GetValue(i).ToString());
            }
         }
         dataReader.Close();
      }
      catch { }
      this.Close();
      return selectResult;
   }
   else
   {
      return selectResult;
   }
}
```

My database table is called "UserList"

The fields in order are as follows:

userid, email, password, lastname, firstname

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This site is amazing!

Comment: You've got some terrible SQL injection vulnerabilities there.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Steve got it right, I missed the single quotes, but pretty sure you need to search on your email field and not the firstname field too.

Your email addresses are stored in the firstname field?

Change it to be your email field

```
private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string email = lemail.Text;
    Dictionary<string, string> dik = sqlClient.Select("UserList", "YOUR_EMAIL_FIELD = " + email);
    var lines = dik.Select(kv => kv.Key + ": " + kv.Value.ToString());
    logged.AppendText(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
}
```

Also, please look into SQL Injection and using parameterized queries.

Comment: I was modifying code and accidentally copied the wrong version. I was indeed looking at the email field. My INSERT method does have parameterized queries. I didn't think you go do SQL injection when pulling FROM the database. The more you know. Thanks!

Comment: @user2908467 The free form text the user entered could terminate your SELECT and execute any other query. It truly is a nasty and easy vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the problem arises from the lack of single quotes around a string value.
I could suggest to add simply quotes around your email value like this

```
Dictionary<string, string> dik = sqlClient.Select("UserList", 
                                                  "firstname = '" + email + "'");
```

but this is really a bad remedy to your problem.

The real change should be passing a parameter list for the query to execute and avoid all this mess with string quotes and sql injections vulnerabilities.

However this require a change in your Select method and in the way you call it

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Select(string table, string WHERE, MySqlParameter[] prms)
{

   string query = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE " + WHERE + "";

   Dictionary<string, string> selectResult = new Dictionary<string, string>();

   if (this.Open())
   {
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
      cmd.Parameters.AddRange(prms);
      MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      try
      {
          ......
      }
      catch { }
      this.Close();
      return selectResult;
   }
   else
   {
      return selectResult;
   }
}
```

And the call should be

```
 List<MySqlParameter> prms = new List<MySqlParameter>()
 MySqlParameter p = new MySqlParameter("@mail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lemail.Text;
 prms.Add(p);
 Dictionary<string, string> dik = sqlClient.Select("UserList", "firstname = @mail", prms.ToArray());
```

There are other critical points in your code albeit not related to your current exception.

1)  If this sqlClient.Count counts the record of your table then the line

```
for (int i = 0; i <= sqlClient.Count("UserList"); i++)
```

loops for one element more than required. Just `i < sqlClient.Count`

2)  In the Select method you swallow the exception and this is really bad because every failure in this critical method will never be known.